# error after build with innosetup

Tags: python-2.7

i wrote a program in python 
and i make a setup file with innosetup.after install my exe file and rum my installed program i got error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ProductionRules.py", line 3, in <module>
  File "zipextimporter.pyo", line 82, in load_module
  File "nltk\__init__.pyo", line 40, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'NoneType' and 'str'
```

this error does not happen when i run my "ProductionRules.py" before converting to exe.
what should i do ?
please help me.